# C# method to remove duplicates from a List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, list

I need a C# method to remove duplicates from a `List<T>` using a custom comparison operation. In .NET 4. Is there one or do I have to write it myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your comparison operation is `IEqualityComparer<T>` or can be converted to it, you're fine with LINQ:

```
var newList = oldList.Distinct(customComparer).ToList();
```

Obviously that creates a *new* list rather than removing elements from the *old* one, but in most cases that's okay. You could always completely replace the contents of the old list with the new list afterwards if not...

Comment: why not do `oldList = oldList.Distinct(customComparer).ToList();`to avoid creating a new list Mr.Skeet?Is it bad?Wouldn't it work?

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins - that won't prevent creation of a new list, it will just overwrite the reference you held to the old one with a reference to the new one.

Comment: @Jonas H What?Seriously?I guess I imagined the memory flow very wrong for overwriting old list.I thought there would be no need for a creation if we use `oldList`.Isn't there any way?Thanks Mr.H.

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins: Yes, there's a big difference between declaring a new variable and creating a new object. `ToList` *always* creates a new list. What you do with it afterwards is up to you.

Answer (score 6):

You could go with [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565318/c-method-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-listt/6565330#6565330), or if you really want to remove duplicates from an *existing* list, something like this would work:

```
public static void RemoveDuplicates<T>(this IList<T> list, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    var uniques = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
    for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (!uniques.Add(list[i]))
        {
            list.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```